# Can I replace more than one node if RF=3 and two dead nodes?

Tags: cassandra

Can I replace more than one dead node if `RF=3` and two dead nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem replacing nodes even with 2 dead ones as long as there are sufficient replicas available to stream from.

If there are 3 nodes in the cluster with `RF=3` then the remaining node will be the only source of data.

For clusters with vnodes and more than 3 nodes and `RF=3`, there is a chance that with 2 dead nodes, a token range(s) may not be available to stream from and you might be forced to restore from backups. Cheers!

Comment: With 02 dead nodes, can I replace those 02 nodes and still keep the token ranges. I tried replace but had to remove 01 node before replacing the other node. in my system ```num_tokens = 8```.

Comment: Without knowing the details of what happened, it's hard for me to comment on why you had to remove the first node. That wouldn't have been necessary and it sounds like something else went wrong. Cheers!